# How to insert data to subdatas in MongoDb?

Tags: java, mongodb

I know how we put datas in the collections but how do we add them in subdatas like in example below?

Jar Files:

> bson-3.4.2.jar,
>   mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar,
>   mongodb-driver-async-3.4.2.jar,
>   mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar

Java Files:

```
     MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
     DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "test" );
     System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

     boolean auth = db.authenticate(myUserName, myPassword);
     System.out.println("Authentication: "+auth);         
     DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("mycol");
     System.out.println("Collection mycol selected successfully");

     BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("title", "MongoDB").
        append("description", "database").
        append("likes", 100).
        append("url", "http://www.instagram.com/").
        append("by", "users");

     coll.insert(doc);
```

MongoDB:

```
{ 
   "_id" : "test",
   "status" : 2,
   "time" : null,
   "instagram" :{
         "description" : "database",
         "likes" : 100,
         "url" : "http://www.instagram.com/",
         "by", "users"
   },
   "batchid" : 15000234
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code to below. Add rest of sub data fields as you needed.

```
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("title", "MongoDB").
            append("description", "database").
            append("likes", 100).
            append("url", "http://www.instagram.com/").
            append("by", "users").
            append("instagram", new BasicDBObject("description","database").append("likes", "likes"));
```

Try using newer api classs. `BasicDBObject`, `DBCollection` & `DB` are old 2.x classes.

Something like.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

boolean auth = db.authenticate(myUserName, myPassword);
System.out.println("Authentication: "+auth);
MongoCollection<Document> coll = database.getCollection("mycol");
System.out.println("Collection mycol selected successfully");

Document doc = new Document("title", "MongoDB").
            append("description", "database").
            append("likes", 100).
            append("url", "http://www.instagram.com/").
            append("by", "users").
            append("instagram", new Document("description","database").append("likes", "likes"));


coll.insertOne(doc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Java, take a look at [jongo](http://jongo.org/) and the "dot notation":

In your case, you could do something like this:

```
collection.update("{ _id: 'test'}").with("{$set: {"instagram.likes": 2}})
```

Comment: Is there a way without using jongo?

Comment: Also dot notation, without jongo: [follow this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33864465/1535071)